# Codename one pick icon new gui builder not working

Tags: java, codenameone

I have started using the new GUI builder. I am trying to do something as simple as adding an image from .res file, but it displays error "could not load image". I am showing the relevant screenshots.
I have uploaded the images to the theme.res file, "ALL images/add images.
Picking images says "unsupported properties",  and when pressing "from res file" nothing happens. If i press "add image" top right, it shows the previously mentioned error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you run from the command line and provide the output in the console? https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html is your theme file named `theme.res` ? Do you have more than one theme?

Comment: Yes, theme.res file, only one theme. I open in terminal, press java -jar designer_1.jar path-to-file.res
, it displays: Error: Unable to access jarfile guibuilder_1.jar

Comment: I started a new project with "get started" , not hello world. It currently works. Thank you. 
Looking forward for the major update this weekend.

Comment: Try guibuilder.jar but you need to set the path to the `.codenameone` directory in the user home directory.